# Creating 3 columns in UIPickerView, also using append function

Tags: swift, append, uipickerview

This is another question of an app I am trying to develop for a small company. Essentially, I want to make it easier for people to find account numbers. The first column in the PickerView is essentially the department. The second will be the task that he/she is going to do, and the third will be the location. I've figured out how to visually make 3 columns, but i cannot figure out how to put it into the code. By that, I mean how to actually set values/selections for the third column. Furthermore, I'm having some issues trying to connect it with the .append function so that only certain options are presented with certain selections in the column. The append function isn't a necessity, but it would be nice to use it if possible.

This is the first app I have ever coded and I "trained myself", hence my amateur mistakes if any. Any help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

cllass Account {
var account: String
var jlCode: [String]
var location: [[String]]

init(account:String, jlCode:[String], location:[[String]]) {
    self.jlCode = jlCode
    self.account = account
    self.location = location
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var accountLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var infoLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var accounts = [Account]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self

    infoLbl.text = """
    test
    """

    //A. PARKS - Tasks for account number 12345678910

    accounts.append(Account(account: "12345678910", jlCode: ["task 1"], location: [["here"]]))

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return accounts.count
    } else if component == 1 {
        let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        return accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode.count
    } else if component == 2 {
        let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selectedjlCode = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let location = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)
        return accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode[selectedjlCode].location.count
    }
    return 3
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == 0 {
        return accounts[row].account
    } else if component == 1 {
        let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        return accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode[row]
    } else if component == 2 {
        let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selectedjlCode = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let selectedLocation = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)
        return accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode[selectedjlCode].location[selectedLocation]
    }
    return nil
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    pickerView.reloadComponent(1)

    let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let selectedjlCode = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
    let account = accounts[selectedAccount].account
    let jlCode = accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode[selectedjlCode]

    accountLbl.text = "Account Number: \(account)\nJL Code: \(jlCode)"

}
}
```

Comment: where is the locations information you want to put in 3rd column? would it be in `Account`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your `titleForRow` function is somewhat lacking. You are currently only serving component 0 (accounts) and... anything that is *not* accounts. You need to be more explicit and deliver the texts accordingly.

To help you on your way, and make it easier for you to comprehend what is happening might I suggest that you create these constants in the top of your class?

```
private let accountsComponent = 0
private let tasksComponent = 1
private let locationsComponent = 2
```

Then you should alter the titleForRow function to cater for all the above tasks:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if component == accountsComponent {
        return accounts[row].account
    } else if component == tasksComponent {
        let selectedAccount = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: accountsComponent)
        return accounts[selectedAccount].jlCode[row]
    } else if component == locationsComponent {
        // THIS IS WHAT IS MISSING
        // You need to return the location strings from this place.
    }
    return nil
}
```

You will need to return the appropriate strings from the `if component == locationsComponent` part...

[edit2]
OK, since you're just starting out I'll go the extra mile:
It's not obvious that you've grasped exactly what the `numberOfRowsInComponent` and `titleForRow` functions are for(?)

The `numberOfRows` tells the component *how many values* each component ("column") contains. The `titleForRow` is where you return the actual text-strings that should be displayed for each row in each component.

So, as I mentioned in my comments, create a Location struct:

```
struct Location {
    var identifier: Int
    var label: String
}
```

In your controller, create an array of this struct.

```
let locations: [Location] = [Location(identifier: 1, label: "Outdoors"),
                             Location(identifier: 2, label: "Indoor"),
                             Location(identifier: 3, label: "Narnia")]
```

Then your numberOfRows should lean on this array to return the appropriate number of rows for the location-component:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    // Only including the parts to return the location-stuff 
    } else if component == 2 {
        return locations.count
    }
    return 0 // This will never be reached as long as the numberOfComponents returns 3
}
```

and the titleForRow:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    // Only including the parts to return the location-stuff 
    } else if component == 2 {
        return locations[row].label
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Dude! I am forever indebted to you. You are really helping me through this. Now I'm having another issue, which is trying to input data into the third column. I've tried this for the past few days, but I'm not exactly sure how to so that it matches with the append function.

Comment: I have: "accounts.append(Account(account: "12345678910", jlCode: ["task 1", "task 2", "task 3", "task 4"]]))" but at what area do I add the location? It also says that 'value of type 'String' has no member location' even though I have defined it. but I'm thinking maybe that is something that can be solved once I actually add the third column.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about your intended model. That is: Are the location-information tied to the tasks, or are they separate from each other? (The latter meaning any task can happen on any location).

Comment: The task can happen at any location. So the task number is dependent on the account. The location is just where the task will be taking place.

Comment: OK, then I'd create a `Location` struct with a `var identifier: Int` and `var label: String`. Let your controller have an array of these and return the `label` from `Locations[row]` in the titleForRow function...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I edited my original post with the code. I'm able to add the location to the account class and initialize, but when I try and start picking data for it, it never shows up - probably because I can't get it to show in the numberOfRowsInComponent/titleForRow section without error. I have an error that says "value of type 'String' has no member 'location'", even though I had referenced/made it. So my two problems are, which may be related and why each one isn't working, is i'm not sure how to select data for the location and also how to properly return it without error.

Comment: It would make it easier to help you if you actually implemented the solution I suggested in your previous question. The idea of modelling it through separate structs is to make it _easier_ as you go forward. Looking at your account-class for instance: Ask yourself _what_ an account actually is. Does an account really have a _location_? Does an account have an _account_? - Probably not. 

Anyways, I've tried to help you with my latest edit above.

Comment: You’re right. It’s easy to get frustrated, especially when it’s with coding so I thank you for your prolonged patience with me. I got it to work and I’m thankful that you have helped me. Thank you truly!